# How to perform some actions based on the position of a div section in a html page in Angular using getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, getboundingclientrect

I have a apply button in a filter bar with several filters , sometimes this apply button will display in the next row instead of showing it in the same row with the other filters. How can I perform a set of actions based on the  position of this apply button. If the apply button is in the next row I want to do set of actions.

```
  <button (click)="apply() "
                    [ngClass]="{'a-btn--disabled': isDisable}" id="apply"
                    mat-raised-button  >Apply
           </button>
```

In component i am using `getBoundingClientRect()`,

```
 const height = document.getElementById('apply').getBoundingClientRect();
 console.log(height);
```

I am trying to get `getBoundingClientRect()` value from top in order to identify it in the first row or the second row. But `getBoundingClientRect().top` returns different values at different times. Therefore can't apply a specific condition based on these `getBoundingClientRect()` value to identify it in the first row or second row. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can just define an element like span above the button, and replace id attribute from button to span.
then you can getBoundingClientRect() from span and it does not change at all.

```
<span id=apply></span>
  <button (click)="apply() "
                    [ngClass]="{'a-btn--disabled': isDisable}"
                    mat-raised-button  >Apply
           </button>
```

Comment: Actually i want to identify when the apply button is in the first row and when it's in the second row separately. But in here it gives different values. I want to apply different conditions for both situations by identifying them

Comment: so you can find boundaries (x,y) position and then make an if statement

Comment: It sometimes give the same value like if apply button is in the first row , if it returns X as 67.when it's in the second row also some times it gives the x value as 67.